# Cannot serialize inherited property into JSON via Json.Net

Tags: c#-4.0, inheritance, serialization, json.net

I am using C# .NET 4.0 and Newtonsoft JSON 4.5.0.11

```
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public interface IProduct
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProductId")]
        int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
    {
        private object _id;

        public T Id
        {
            get { return (T)_id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Product : BaseEntity<int>, IProduct
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to serialize part of object and I use interfaces with declared concrete properties  to do this.

The serialization looks like:

```
Product product = new Product { Id = 1, Name = "My Product", Quantity = 5};
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

Expected result is:

```
{"ProductId": 1, "Name": "My Product"}
```

But actual result is:

```
{"Name": "My Product"}
```

How can I serialize this object correctly?

---

UPD: Looked at the source code of json.net and came to the conclusion that this is a bug with grab information about object through ReflectionUtils.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
public interface IProduct
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
{
    private object _id;
    [JsonProperty]
    public T Id
    {
        get { return (T)_id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Product : BaseEntity<int>, IProduct
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to use JsonProperty and JsonObject in a base class, because it placed in another project (library), which doesn't have reference to Newtonsoft JSON dll.